# Closing parenthesis of a multi-line function call must be on a line by itself

Tags: phpcs, php-cs-fixer

I am getting this message from phpcs. my code is:

```
$userdata["expirydate"] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(date("H"), date(
        "i"), date("s"), date("m"), date("d") - 1, date("y")));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `date("i")` function call spans multiple lines. When this happens, that rule is enforcing that the closing parenthesis be on a line by itself.

If you want to adhere to that rule, you've got a a few options for reformatting your code.

You could use the PHPCS diff report to see how PHPCS wants you to format it. In this case, using `--report=diff` shows:

```
--- temp.php
+++ PHP_CodeSniffer
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
 <?php
 $userdata["expirydate"] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(date("H"), date(
-    "i"), date("s"), date("m"), date("d") - 1, date("y")));
+    "i"
+), date("s"), date("m"), date("d") - 1, date("y")));
```

Which means PHPCS thinks the smallest change you could make would be to write your code like this:

```
$userdata["expirydate"] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(date("H"), date(
    "i"
), date("s"), date("m"), date("d") - 1, date("y")));
```

Which is valid, but not great.

You could put it all on one long line, which is still valid:

```
$userdata["expirydate"] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(date("H"), date("i"), date("s"), date("m"), date("d") - 1, date("y")));
```

You could split up the main `date()` call to make it valid and keep the line lengths shorter:

```
$userdata["expirydate"] = date(
    "Y-m-d H:i:s",
    mktime(date("H"), date("i"), date("s"), date("m"), date("d") - 1, date("y"))
);
```

Or you could even put every argument on a new line:

```
$userdata["expirydate"] = date(
    "Y-m-d H:i:s",
    mktime(
        date("H"),
        date("i"),
        date("s"),
        date("m"),
        date("d") - 1,
        date("y")
    )
);
```

It really depends on which code block you find more readable, and which code block fits best with your existing coding standard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Greg, I has use one long line code but it was showing something like 
"phpcs: Line exceeds 120 characters; contains 164 characters", So I changed it. Now I put every argument on a new line
and issue has solved. Thanks.

Comment: @Hemant Happy to help. Glad you found a format that works for you.